# Display of referenced entity fields with or without link to entity, depending on type of referenced entity

Tags: theming, entities

I need to display a publication of a group.
The authors of a publication can be members of the group or not.

In the edit page of the publication the authors can be added through a referenced entity field. References can be made to node of type "member" or to node of type "external author".

I would like to output the result as:

Title of publication
Author 1 (link to the member's personal page), Author 2 (no link to other page), Author 3 (link to personal page), Author 4 (link to personal page)

So,

if referenced entity is of type member -> [author](/node/*)

if referenced entity is of type external author -> author

like:

[author 1](/node/*) author 2 [author 3](/node/*) [author 4](/node/*)

The twig template contains the code:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <span{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to adjust the code to display the publication the way I would like.

Thanks in advance